# Assigning interval number to numbers in vector

Tags: r

Say I have a df like this which show the start and end times of five intervals:

```
     start      end id
#  326.019  340.133  1
#  451.142  469.626  2
#  597.985  617.004  3
#  778.896  797.714  4
# 1014.590 1038.280  5

df = structure(list(start = c(326.019, 451.142, 597.985, 778.896, 
1014.59), end = c(340.133, 469.626, 617.004, 797.714, 1038.28
), id = 1:5), .Names = c("start", "end", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also have a vector of times, which may appear inside or outside of these intervals:

```
x = c(120.485, 326.019, 329.089, 337.564, 337.897, 340.133, 451.142, 
456.046, 456.213, 456.847, 458.549, 459.15, 459.416, 459.517, 
462.319, 464.788, 469.626, 590.345, 597.985, 598.152, 599.353, 
600.421, 601.756, 602.523, 602.857, 603.291, 603.758, 604.926, 
605.96, 606.827, 607.161, 608.362, 608.629, 609.764, 610.331, 
610.998, 611.098, 611.165, 617.004, 778.896, 781.065, 782.299, 
782.9, 783.2, 783.5, 783.934, 785.336, 785.669, 787.771, 789.039, 
789.606, 790.207, 791.642, 792.409, 797.714, 1014.59, 1015.29, 
1015.69, 1016.13, 1016.83, 1017.1, 1017.26, 1019.1, 1019.36, 
1019.5, 1019.83, 1020.77, 1021.2, 1022.4, 1022.8, 1023.14, 1023.84, 
1023.94, 1024.44, 1024.97, 1025, 1026.91, 1026.97, 1027.74, 1028.27, 
1029.17, 1029.71, 1029.81, 1032.01, 1032.11, 1033.31, 1035.35, 
1035.68, 1036.75, 1038.28)
```

I want to produce another vector that declares whether the value of vector x is i) outside all intervals, or ii) which interval it is inside of.

I thought about using `findInterval` and started like this:

```
y <- c(rbind(df$start, df$end)) #get a vector of start-end-start-end etc times
findInterval(x, y)
```

The output is like this:

```
 [1]  0  1  1  1  1  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  7  7  7
[43]  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
[85]  9  9  9  9  9 10
```

I could process this to work out the interval location of index=0 result produced by `findInterval` but that doesn't seem to be the best method. Are there better ways?

If times have the same time as a start or end, they should be considered as belonging to that interval. `findInterval` doesn't appear to do this -e.g. the last value of x is 1038.28 but it is considered to be in a new interval. I would like it to be assigned as belonging to interval=5.

Values of x that do not appear in intervals should get NA.

Comment: But you only have 5 intervals, in the output there are 9

Comment: You might need "rightmost.closed = TRUE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[.(start = x), on="start", roll=Inf][start > end, id := NA_integer_]$id

 [1] NA  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 NA  3
[20]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[39]  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5
[58]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
[77]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

I'm not sure if this has the desired output, though, since none was given explicitly in the OP.

Comment: Another reason to learn more `data.table` - thanks, the output is exactly right.